# cannot make multiple thread safe calls to windows forms control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, thread-safety

I am enhancing a c# win forms application that interacts with SalesForce CRM via webservices.

I have the below code to make a 'thread safe' update to a label on my form:

```
 delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

 private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.lblAccessStatus.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.lblAccessStatus.Text = text;
            this.lblAccessStatus.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

My form (called `SFDetachifier.cs`) has a button execute which takes the dates of two calendar controls then calls:

```
lblAccessStatus.Visible = true;
picProgress.Visible = true;

string fromDate = dtManualFromDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + fromTime;
string toDate = dtManualToDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + toTime;
string[] arg = new string[] { "S1", fromDate, toDate };
SFCtrl._SessionLog.Append("Manual detach requested on " + SFOrgName + "\n");
SFCtrl._SessionLog.Append("Date range requested: " + fromDate + " to " + toDate + "\n");

bgProcessing_Production.RunWorkerAsync(arg);
```

`bgProcessing_Production` has the below code for the Background worker which includes a call to `setText`

```
private void bgProcessing_Production_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        String[] args = (String[])e.Argument;
        e.Result = args[0];

        // clear the datagrid view
        gvTaskCases.DataSource = null;
        //gvTaskCases.Rows.Clear();

        //if (gvTaskCases.Rows.Count != 0)
        //    {
        //    gvTaskCases.Rows.Clear(); // .Update();
        //    }

        SetText("login to SalesForce (on " + SFOrgName + ") ...please wait");
```

Now, when I run my application I set some dates, then execute the above code by clicking the execute button, it does it's work (calling SalesForce XML web services) and puts the results in a grid.

that all works fine, the problem occurrs when I try to run the procedure again (for example with different dates)

Then I get an error **'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'**

I don't understand, I have a delegate setup?

What am I doing wrong - I'm guessing that when the backround worker is run again it runs on a new thread, thus being thread unsafe.

How can I fix this error please?

Comment: Just checking - could the `gvTaskCases.DataSource = null;` be causing the exception?

Comment: Interesting that the control name in the error message is ''

Comment: both good points above, however, ` gvTaskCases.DataSource = null;` is not the problem (although I did get some thread safety issues with that control in the commented code above the call to `setText`

Comment: BeginInvoke would fix the problem? I don't see why but you may give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten things up a bit using anonymous delegates like this:

```
    private void removeGridDS()
    {
        this.gvTaskCases.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            if (this.gvTaskCases.DataSource != null)
            {
                this.gvTaskCases.DataSource = null;
            }
        });
    }

    private void clear_gvTaskCases()
    {
        this.gvTaskCases.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            if (this.gvTaskCases.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                this.gvTaskCases.Rows.Clear();
            }
        });
    }
```

Now you don't need the hard-coded delegates.  Also, you weren't using the passed in bools.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I ended up doing in order to get around this issue, as one of the comments above suggested, it looks likely that it's the calls to the control `gvTaskCases` which is throwing the error so I have created thread safe method calls on that control too:

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
delegate void clear_gvTaskCasesCallback(bool clearIt);
delegate void remove_gvTaskCasesDSCallback( bool removeDS);

private void removeGridDS(bool removeDS)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.gvTaskCases.InvokeRequired)
        {
        remove_gvTaskCasesDSCallback d = new remove_gvTaskCasesDSCallback(removeGridDS);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { removeDS });
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.gvTaskCases.DataSource !=null)
            {
            this.gvTaskCases.DataSource=null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void clear_gvTaskCases(bool clearIt)
    {
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (this.gvTaskCases.InvokeRequired)
    {
        clear_gvTaskCasesCallback d = new clear_gvTaskCasesCallback(clear_gvTaskCases);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { clearIt });
        }
        else
        {
        if (this.gvTaskCases.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
        this.gvTaskCases.Rows.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, don't do that.  Just reset the data binding before you call RunWorkerAsync.  Makes no difference, just a lot less code.  The same applies to setting the label's Text, no obvious reason to do it from the worker so might as well do it a millisecond early.